# Multiple inheritance: QGraphicsPixmapItem and QGraphicsTextItem

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, qgraphicsitem

I need the have a object that combines the characteristics of both `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and `QGraphicsTextItem` (image + text).

Is multiple inheritance the best way to do it or are there any contraindications? If there are, what would you suggest?

Comment: Hmm this could turn more into opinions than facts, but using interface(s) is an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think multiple inheritance is not a good idea in Qt, as far as I know it is not recommended. Im don't know exactly why (possibly because of their signals and slots mechanism).

Now to your question, have you though of using QGraphicsItemGroup?

Gerald

Comment: Hum ... QGraphicsItemGroup seems a better idea thant a QGraphicsItem subsclass with a QGraphicsPixmapItem and a QGraphicsTextItem.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to inherit neither.  If what you need is an object that consistently displays an image next to some text, you are better off creating your own object that inherits `QGraphicsItem` that has a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and has a `QGraphicsTextItem`.  Then you don't have to deal with the difficulties of multiple inheritance at all.